# C# Foreach loop with mySQL Command param

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to use a foreach loop to update every checkbox in my mysql database.

This is what I have:

```
string Query = "update agenda.exercises set @checkboxname='1' where Date='" + currentDate + "';";
```

With cmd param:                             `MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkboxname", isTenured);`

When I remove the command param and turn it into normal text, it works. When I try to use the command param as the text, it doesn't work.

Here's my full code:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in allCheckboxes.Columns)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dc.ToString());

    //var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    string Query = "update agenda.exercises set @checkboxname='1' where Date='" + currentDate + "';";

    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
    MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkboxname", dc.ToString());

    MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
    MyConn2.Open();
    MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

    while (MyReader2.Read())
    {

    }

    MyConn2.Close();
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `SqlParameter` for column names

Comment: Parameters are for values, not for column names. That's why your plain text "works"

Answer (score 0):

You have your column name as parameter that will not work you have to put the values in your parameters instead.

Something like this :

```
foreach (DataColumn col in allCheckboxes.Columns)
{
    string Query = "update agenda.exercises set " + col.ToString() + " = @value where Date = @CurrentDate;";
    using (MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2))
        {
            MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value ", true);
            MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentDate", currentDate);
            MyConn2.Open();
            MyCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP need to update different columns (based on which `CheckBox` was checked).

Comment: @Fabio OK I missed that I have updated my answer for this

Comment: Your code will not compile - copy/paste not very good tool :)

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed a + in the Query assigment and the () for the using commands. The latter I have indeed copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SqlParameter` for column names.
You can put column name in the query without parameter. But definitely use `SqlParameter` for passed values, even for hardcoded values (`true` for example)

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in allCheckboxes.Columns)
{
    string Query = $"UPDATE agenda.exercises SET {dc.ToString()} = @True 
                     WHERE Date = @CurrentDate;";
    using (MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2))
        {
            MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@True ", true);
            MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentDate", currentDate);
            MyConn2.Open();
            MyCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Personaly I don't like this approach (dynamically create sql queries), I will create own method for every checkbox.